# Deseo obtener en éste formato "Nov 18 - 24" los días Jueves y miercoles donde 18 sería Jueves y 24 sería Miercoles de la siguiente semana

Tags: javascript, next.js

Estoy teniendo complicación con la validación, tengo algo así que calcula el Mes, luego el día, y despues le suma 6 para que sea el miercoles, pero cuando es un jueves 26, le suma 6 y el siguiente día Miercoles sería 32, podrían ayudarme?

```
    const dateDealM = new Date();
    if(dateDealM.getDay() == 0){
      const day = dateDealM.getDate() + 4
      setDay(day);
    }if(dateDealM.getDay() == 1){
      const day = dateDealM.getDate() + 3
      setDay(day);
    }if(dateDealM.getDay() == 2){
      const day = dateDealM.getDate() + 2
      setDay(day);
    }if(dateDealM.getDay() == 3){
      const day = dateDealM.getDate() + 1
      setDay(day);
    }if (dateDealM.getDay() == 4){
      const day = dateDealM.getDate()
      setDay(day);
    }if (dateDealM.getDay() == 5){
      const day = dateDealM.getDate() -1 
      setDay(day);
    }if(dateDealM.getDay() == 6){
      const day = dateDealM.getDate() -2
      setDay(day);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Habría que ver que hace el metodo setDay, pero la forma correcta de asignar es usando 'setDate' como en este ejemplo:

```
    var originalDayOfWeek = date.getDay();
    
    var oneDayAfter = new Date(date);
    oneDayAfter.setDate(oneDayAfter.getDate() + 1);
```